# How to send a post request with params to flask server from Android?

Tags: java, android, python, flask, request

I am trying to make a post request with `AsyncHttpClient` from an android app to a python flask server but the parameters aren't recognized, why?
When the server receives the request it looks like `POST /testing HTTP/1.1`.

This is the Android code:

```
public void encodeImagetoString() {
    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {

        protected void onPreExecute() {

        };

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            BitmapFactory.Options options = null;
            options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inSampleSize = 3;
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgPath,
                    options);
            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
            byte[] byte_arr = stream.toByteArray();
            encodedString = Base64.encodeToString(byte_arr, 0);
            return "";
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String msg) {
            AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
            HashMap<String, String> param = new HashMap<String, String>();
            param.put("image", encodedString);
            params = new RequestParams(param);
            triggerImageUpload();
        }
    }.execute(null, null, null);
}

public void triggerImageUpload() {
    makeHTTPCall();
}
public void makeHTTPCall() {

    AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
    Log.w("Parametrul este:",params.toString());
     client.post("http://localhost/testing",
            params, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {

            });


}
```

The flask server is:

```
@app.route('/testing', methods=['POST','GET'])
def testing(image):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        return image
        #return "Image was received"
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return "Get request"


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(threaded=True)
```

Comment: You have a variable called `params` which contains the `RequestParams` and then you call the `triggerImageUpload()` where the method doesn't exactly know what `params` is. You could change the `triggerImageUpload(RequestParams params)` and similarly to `makeHTTPCall(....)` for this to work

Comment: params is field of the class. It is also visible from makeHTTPCall.

Comment: The flask code expects an `image` variable but it wasn't specified in the `route`, so I believe this code breaks. Also, remember you could use `request.args.get("image")` to get any parameter behind the `?`.

Comment: I fixed that error, but the problem is still there. The request doesn't get parameters.